# app log file miss most log info when do concurrence testing

Tags: java, logging, concurrency, log4j

i use JMeter to do concurrence testing for web app.

environment : linux , JMeter 2.6, tomcat 6.0.35, log4j 1.2.14,

i use appender of my company which extends RollingFileAppender, it's used for creating corresponding log file according to the different user and login ip, e.g. user1-233.111-app.log.20121112

i set the threads of JMeter is 50, then run the jmeter script to test web app, there are 50 log files in tomcat/logs, but there are next problems :

1. each log file miss most log info, e.g. user1-233.111-app.log.20121112 only has one line info, but it should has much log info
2. user1's log file contains user2's log info, e.g. in user1-233.111-app.log.20121112, there are some lines like - INFO [user2] ..........

there is not user1-233.111-app.log.20121112.1, user1-233.111-app.log.20121112.2 etc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How should we find a bug in your own custom-appender without the sources? If your tests runs the original DailyRollingFileAppender are there missing entries, too?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, my company's appender extends RollingFileAppender.

Answer (score 0):

This is surely a bug in your file appender extension class. Show code here so that you can get answer .

Comment: i also tried SiftingAppender of Logback, but also found that some user's log file only has one line info.

Comment: after using SiftingAppender of Logback, i found a querstion, e.g. i test application with 50 users, and their log files are : 50update.log, 50update1.log,50update2.log, .., 50update49.log, after finish, all these log files are normal.  Then i run test again with 50 users, use different name, then the log files are : fifty.log,fifty1.log,...,fitfy49.log.  This time i found that some 50update log files miss log info, e.g. 50update1.log only has one line info, and this line info is the same as 1st line of fifty1.log.@PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE